# php mysql array of results issue

Tags: php

I have database for books and authors. the relationship between these two entities is many to many so there's a joint table between them.

1. `books` has `books.book_id` as primary, `authors.author_id` as primary and the joint table `book_authors` has: `book_authors.book_id` and `book_authors.author_id`.
2. Each book has more than one author.

What I am trying to do is to have a php page that shows each book in one line then under, it says: author1:...., author2(if applicable)

I want my php to look somewhat like:

```
Book Name: THE BOOK NAME
Author(s): joe- John- Sara
```

I used the following code and the problem is that it returns with single results. So if book1 is authored by more than one author, it's gonna show more than once each time with a different author. what i am trying to do is to get each book followed by an array of authors

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","myusername","mypassword");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("mydb", $con);

$result1 = mysql_query("
    SELECT books.title, authors.fname, authors.lname 
    FROM books, book_authors, authors  
    WHERE books.book_id = book_authors.book_id 
    AND authors.author_id=book_authors.author_id");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
  {
print "<h3>Book Name:</h3>";
  echo $row ['title'];
print "<br />";
print "Author(s):";
  echo $row ['fname'];
  echo $row ['lname'];
  echo "<br />";
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because, you're using `Group By` in your query. Please follow some `SQL` tutorials first.

Comment: Can you var_dump example output from that query?

Comment: @HamzaWaqas i took the group by and what i got is each book listed more than once each time with one of the authors.

Comment: How many records you're getting from the query running in the navigator?

Comment: @HamzaWaqas I'm getting more than a 100 records which is not correct. They have to be 50 books with 1-4 authors under each book.

Comment: Did you tried by using `INNER JOIN` in the query? I think if you're getting wrong record count, then it must be `sql cartesian` yet,.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query that should do the trick:

```
SELECT books.title, authors.fname, authors.lname FROM books LEFT JOIN
book_authors ON books.book_id = book_authors.book_id LEFT JOIN authors
ON authors.author_id = book_authors.author_id
```

You'll have to double-check that the book_id is the same for row author.

Another way to do it is to first select the books, and then in your foreach loop, look up the author(s) for that book via the book_authors table.

Another thing to note is that [mysql_*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)  functions are deprecated and you should look into using [mysqli_*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php).

Comment: that looks great. but what i am actually looking for is the foreach loop. i will check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your sql query is incorrect. It needs to be formated like so.

`SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name1
INNER JOIN table_name2
ON table_name1.column_name=table_name2.column_name`

`SELECT books.title, authors.fname, authors.lname 
FROM books INNER JOIN authors ON
books.book_id = authors.book_id`

SELECT Persons.LastName, Persons.FirstName, Orders.OrderNo
FROM Persons
INNER JOIN Orders
ON Persons.P_Id=Orders.P_Id
ORDER BY Persons.LastName

Answer (score 0):

Try `group_concat`

```
SELECT books.title, group_concat(concat(authors.fname,' ',authors.lname) AS Authors
FROM books, book_authors, authors  
WHERE books.book_id = book_authors.book_id 
AND authors.author_id=book_authors.author_id
GROUP BY books.title
```

then in PHP

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
  {
     print "<h3>Book Name:</h3>";
     echo $row ['title'];
     print "<br />";
     $authors = explode($row['Authors']); //array of authors

     for($authors as $author)
     {
        echo($author.'<br/>')
     }
   }
```

You can use JOIN instead

```
SELECT books.title, GROUP_CONCAT(authors.fname) AS Authors 
FROM books
LEFT JOIN book_authors ON books.book_id = book_authors.book_id
LEFT JOIN authors ON book_authors.author_id = authors.author_id
GROUP BY books.title
```

Comment: it makes perfect sense and this is what i am looking for. I tried it though and for some reason, no results are showing now at all. Any idea?

Comment: replace this portion and see what happens: `group_concat(authors.fname)`

Comment: did that and still nothing changed!

Comment: I don't think it's related to this because I just tried select books.title, authors.fname as authors from ... and still nothing is showing

Comment: Now that I used the join, I am getting the same amount of results I used to get when I first used my code above but a little organized. I am getting book1 with one author and then i get book1 again with another author. Still they are not all together in one line under each book

Comment: Sorry you need to add the Group By this time - I only intend you substitute it into the query I posted earlier

Comment: I did but it doesn't seem to be working as I want it. Thanks anyway